# Why can't Vim see the tags file, despite being in the same directory?

Tags: tags, ctags

I'm in folder `E:\dir\python_file.py`, `:pwd` shows `E:\dir`. `:e tags` opens the tags file I generated with `ctags -R`.

I've got `tags` set to what seems reasonable: `set tags?` shows `set tags=./tags,tags;E:\`. Verbose `set tags` shows only my vimrc.

Using `:tag method_name` throws two errors: `E433: No tags file` and `E426: tag not found: method_name`.

I'm on Windows.

Comment: `gvim -u NONE -U NONE` has it working fine, so I must just have a plugin doing something weird.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`wildignore` had a trailing comma.

My vimrc had `set wildignore=*.png,` which had a trailing comma. Changing it do `set wildignore=*.png` solved my issue.

It turns out, after looking at `:set` for a while, that `ftplugin/python.vim`  does `set wildignore+=*.pyc` somewhere, because just `set wildignore=*.png,` isn't enough to break the tags. So the wildignore that I had, once I opened a .py file, was `wildcard=*.png,,*.pyc`, and if you open vim with `vim -u NONE -U NONE`, tags will break.

Vim must do some concatenation adding a comma if the setting isn't empty, but doesn't check for an existing trailing comma. Think I just found a bug.

---

Turns out it was a bug, and it has since been [resolved](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/365).

Comment: Doing some testing, using a vimrc with only `set wildignore=*.png,` isn't enough to cause this, so maybe parsing gets stuck with any trailing comma?

Comment: We'll see if it really is a bug https://code.google.com/p/vim/issues/detail?id=365

Comment: I would claim not a bug. This setting is a comma separated list. Since there is already a trailing comma in the setting it means that an empty item is in the setting. (Whether an empty item means anything is probably dependent on the setting). When you do `+=` on a setting  that is a comma separated list it will always add a comma unless it is empty since you are trying to add something to the list. Using the existing comma would remove the empty item. Which is probably unexpected. (`:help :set+=`) (However the empty item ignoring everything could be a bug)

Comment: @FDinoff that's a good point, there could be a setting which expects an empty item.

Comment: @Viet No problem man!

Comment: @FDinoff It ended up getting fixed.