# vim can't process tags

Tags: tags, ctags

I generated tags files and I'm using the following command in my `.vimrc`:

```
:set tags=./tags;
```

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> I get the following error:

```
E433: No tags file
E426: tag not found: poll_wait
```

I'm not sure that the tag file is actually loaded.

```
:verbose set tags?
  tags=./tags;
        Last set from ~/.vimrc
```

How can I debug it further ?

Comment: Maybe this will be useful? https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3317/why-cant-vim-see-the-tags-file-despite-being-in-the-same-directory maybe that trailing `;` after `./tags` is breaking something?

Answer (score 2):

Your `'tags'` setting should search for tags named `tags` in the current directory:

> When a file name starts with "./", the '.' is replaced with the path
>   of the current file.  But only when the 'd' flag is not included in
>   'cpoptions'.

You could check the compatibility options that they don't include `d` with `:set cpo?`.

Also, files named `tags` would be found in parent directories (according to [`:help file-searching`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#file-searching)):

> The stop-directories are appended to the path (for the 'path' option) or to the filename (for the 'tags' option) with a ';'.  If you want no stop-directory ("search upward till the root directory) just use ';'.

So, all is looking fine (assuming a tags file actually is there). [`:help 'tags'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27tags%27) also provides a great troubleshooting tip:

> The tagfiles() function can be used to get a list of the file names actually used.

You can use that one with `:echo`. Good luck!